# Terraform Upload Azure File Share

Tags: azure, storage, terraform

As part of an Azure ACI definition Terraform script, I'm creating an azurerm_storage_share which I want to then upload some files to, before mounting to my container.

As far as I can tell, the right way to access the share once created is via SMB.  This rules out all the Terraform provisioners (except local-exec) which support only SSH or WinRM.

So I'm thinking the most efficient, maintainable way to do this is to local-exec to a script that runs azure-cli commands like az storage upload ... ?  That way TF does what it does best (orchestration) and have az do config provisioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. Terrafrom could not directly access to Azure File share and upload files to it.

Based on my knowledge, maybe you could store your files in a Linux VM and [install Azure Cli 2.0](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest) on it. Then you could write a script to upload files to Azure file share like below:

```
#!/bin/bash
# A simple Azure Storage example script

export AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT=<storage_account_name>
export AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY=<storage_account_key>

az storage file upload --share-name myshare --source ~/temp/samplefile.txt
```

More information about this please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-azure-cli).

Then you could SSH to this VM and execute this script on Terraform.

Comment: Thanks.  It's a working solution, I'll give it a try.  I would prefer something that doesn't require an intermediate VM to spin up, perform configuration, then tear down again, but it looks to be the only way right now.  I can't see a  serverless solution either.  Actually, rolling another container to perform configuration would probably make the most sense.

Comment: @TheOperator Based on my knowledge, it is not possible with a server to execute a script.

Comment: Given that the container I'm deploying is actually a custom web server running a webapp, might I actually be better off using the web app for containers service?  Is that service implemented in Terraform?

Comment: Hi, web app do you mean Azure web app(Paas) or web app on a VM?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload a file to a container in a storage account in Azure, you can use this resource:

```
resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "copyfile" {
  name                   = "remotefilename.txt"
  storage_account_name   = azurerm_storage_account.mystorageaccount.name
  storage_container_name = azurerm_storage_container.mycontainer.name
  type                   = "Block"
  source                 = "localfilename.txt"
}
```

More info from TF docs:

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/storage_blob